# I want complex bash if statment ( if file not empty and and file not empty and file not contain string)

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want bash if where I test if file1.txt and file2.txt contain at least some text and if file3.txt does not contain certain line. Something like this, but error here:

```
if [ -s file1.txt ] && [ -s file2.txt ] && [! grep -q "^SEQADV" file3.txt ]
```

Sorry if bit similar question exists, but I never found so complex if discussed here.

Comment: So, what's the error message? What steps have you tried to debug it?

Comment: [!: command not found
I tried other mix of [ and ( but have no idea witch one is correct.

Comment: try to insert a blank between `[!`, it cannot parse `[!` as one command, but separately

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`if [[ -s file1.txt && -s file2.txt && -z "$(grep "^SEQADV" file3.txt)" ]]`

**UPD**: yep, grepping whole file is kinda redundant here, so @dogbase's answer is right:

`if [[ -s file1.txt && -s file2.txt ]] && ! grep -q "^SEQADV" file3.txt`

Comment: This is inefficient, because it keeps scanning even after grep has found the first match. Much better to use `grep -q` and test its exit status rather than its output.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need brackets around the `grep` condition. It can be done like this:

```
if [ -s file1.txt ] && [ -s file2.txt ] && ! grep -q "^SEQADV" file3.txt
```

or, using `[[` :

```
if [[ -s file1.txt && -s file2.txt ]] && ! grep -q "^SEQADV" file3.txt
```